# Скрывать Dropdown при изменении размеров экрана

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Делал по шаблону https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-navbar-login-sign-in-form `Dropdown` меню. Столкнулся с проблемой, при переходе с мобильного разрешения экрана на десктопное с открытым `Dropdown` он должен закрываться.
Попробовал сделать с помощью удаления класса `open` который отвечает за состояние `Dropdown`, но не получилось. Прошу помочь с решением проблемы.

```
$(document).resize(function () {
  var screen = $(window);

  if(screen.width() > 768) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае нужно заменить `document` на `window` и все сработает.

Comment: из-за невнимательности даже не заметил, спасибо большое!

Comment: Правда у меня сработал эвент, но что-то не закрывается все равно... у меня jquery говорит что нет элемента с классом open на той странице, которую вы указали в вопросе. Ну ладно, главное что у вас сработало =)